# how to format oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@64b6887

Tags: oracle

We are using timestamp datatype in oracle 10g. in database data
coming properly but in the app the timestamp will come like `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@31c2bcfc`.

```
{"isSuccessful":true,"resultSet":[{"PAN_NUMBER":"befpd9907G","NATIONALITY":"Indian","GUARDIAN_NAME":"guard1","THIRD_APPLICANT":"Third","MOTHER_MAIDEN_NAME":"Mother","ACCOUNT_TYPE":"AccType","MARITAL_STATUS":"Mststus","STATE":"state","CARD_TYPE":"def","MINOR":"no","EDUCATION":"double","LAST_NAME":"last","SSN_NUMBER":"ssn34","FIRST_NAME":"first","PIN_CODE":"5600","EXPIRY_DATE":"oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@7a628b9a","AADHAR_NUMBER":"123456789012","COUNTRY":"coun","ANNUAL_INCOME":4.25,"PREFERRED_NAME":"prefered","CATEGORY":"Gen","SECOND_APPLICANT":"Second","GENDER":"gender","APPLICATION_FORM_DATE":"oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@31c2bcfc"}]}
```

Where did i do a mistake?

Comment: This is the result of a  `.toString()` call on an Oracle JDBC timestamp object. Instead of that, it should be properly formatted.

Comment: If all is good in the database, but wrong in the app, why is this tagged with `oracle` and nothing else? It seems "Oracle" is the only thing that works properly, your problem/question is with something else (java? JDBC?) Please tag accordingly.